# how to pass the result of an aggregate mediator to back to the calling sequence

Tags: clone, aggregate, mediator, wso2-esb

I have created a custom proxy service that performs a few tasks:

- based on the input, different handling services must be called for which message transformation must take place. For this, I use a switch mediator with a payload mediator, and handle the response with the xsl mediator,
- for one of the request types, two different services must be called and the result combined. For this, I want to use the clone mediator and handle the results with the aggregate mediator.

My question is: is it possible to use the aggregate mediator without using a send mediator in the body to pass back the result? After the aggregate mediator (which is part of a switch branch) I want to do some generic handling and not immediately send back the result to the client.

Example:
Outsequence:

```
<outSequence>
        <log level="full" description="logReturn"/>
        <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
        <switch source="get-property('target')">
            <case regex="RDW">
                <sequence key="RDWOutSequence"/>
            </case>
            <case regex="SmartPark">
                <xslt key="conf:xsl/Cale-QueryVehicle/SmartPark2Vehicle.xsl" description="Easypark2Vehicle"/>
            </case>
            <default>
                <xslt key="conf:xsl/Cale-QueryVehicle/Table2Vehicle.xsl" description="Table2Vehicle"/>
            </default>
        </switch>
        <call-template target="Cale-Logger" description="logOutDb">
            <with-param xmlns:p="http://xmlns.redora.com/QueryVehicle" name="username" value="{$body/p:QueryVehicleRequest/p:username}"/>
            <with-param name="service" value="Cale-QueryVehicle"/>
        </call-template>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
```

RDWOutSequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="RDWOutSequence">
<log level="custom">
    <property name="before_aggregate" value="property_value"/>
</log>
<property name="ROOT" scope="default">
    <root:rootelement xmlns:root="www.wso2esb.com"/>
</property>
<aggregate id="RDW">
    <completeCondition timeout="10000">
        <messageCount min="-1" max="-1"/>
    </completeCondition>
    <onComplete expression="//OPENB-VRTG-INFO" enclosingElementProperty="ROOT">
        <log level="full">
            <property name="in_aggregate" value="property_value"/>
        </log>
        <enrich>
            <source type="envelope" clone="true"/>
            <target type="property" property="aggregateBody"/>
        </enrich>
    </onComplete>
</aggregate>
<enrich>
    <source type="property" clone="true" property="aggregateBody"/>
    <target type="body"/>
</enrich>
<log level="custom" description="">
    <property name="after_aggregate" value="property_value"/>
    <property name="test" expression="get-property('ROOT')"/>
    <property name="aggregateBody" expression="get-property('aggregateBody')"/>
</log>
</sequence>
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you're using (or simplified) - this would be easier for us to help you

Comment: altered the question with some code. Hope this clarifies my question.